# org.springframework.boot.context.event.ApplicationFailedEvent cannot be cast to org.springframework.boot.web.context.WebServerInitializedEvent

Tags: java, spring, maven, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I am getting following error while running spring application. Please I need some help to resolve this. I will appreciate if someone can tell me how I can debug and resolve this issue. I am just going through Internet and doing different combinations in my `pom.xml` file.

My log

```
  org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.CommandAcceptanceException: Error executing DDL via JDBC Statement
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.GenerationTargetToDatabase.accept(GenerationTargetToDatabase.java:67) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.10.Final.jar:5.2.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaMigrator.applySqlString(AbstractSchemaMigrator.java:525) [hibernate-core-5.2.10.Final.jar:5.2.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaMigrator.applySqlStrings(AbstractSchemaMigrator.java:470) [hibernate-core-5.2.10.Final.jar:5.2.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaMigrator.createTable(AbstractSchemaMigrator.java:273) [hibernate-core-5.2.10.Final.jar:5.2.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.GroupedSchemaMigratorImpl.performTablesMigration(GroupedSchemaMigratorImpl.java:71) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.10.Final.jar:5.2.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaMigrator.performMigration(AbstractSchemaMigrator.java:203) [hibernate-core-5.2.10.Final.jar:5.2.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaMigrator.doMigration(AbstractSchemaMigrator.java:110) [hibernate-core-5.2.10.Final.jar:5.2.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.performDatabaseAction(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:183) [hibernate-core-5.2.10.Final.jar:5.2.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.process(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:72) [hibernate-core-5.2.10.Final.jar:5.2.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:309) [hibernate-core-5.2.10.Final.jar:5.2.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:452) [hibernate-core-5.2.10.Final.jar:5.2.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:889) [hibernate-core-5.2.10.Final.jar:5.2.10.Final]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:57) [spring-orm-5.0.0.RC3.jar:5.0.0.RC3]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:358) [spring-orm-5.0.0.RC3.jar:5.0.0.RC3]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:384) [spring-orm-5.0.0.RC3.jar:5.0.0.RC3]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:373) [spring-orm-5.0.0.RC3.jar:5.0.0.RC3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1776) [spring-beans-5.0.0.RC3.jar:5.0.0.RC3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1712) [spring-beans-5.0.0.RC3.jar:5.0.0.RC3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:582) [spring-beans-5.0.0.RC3.jar:5.0.0.RC3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:499) [spring-beans-5.0.0.RC3.jar:5.0.0.RC3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:312) [spring-beans-5.0.0.RC3.jar:5.0.0.RC3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.0.0.RC3.jar:5.0.0.RC3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:310) [spring-beans-5.0.0.RC3.jar:5.0.0.RC3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200) [spring-beans-5.0.0.RC3.jar:5.0.0.RC3]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1083) ~[spring-context-5.0.0.RC3.jar:5.0.0.RC3]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:858) ~[spring-context-5.0.0.RC3.jar:5.0.0.RC3]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:549) ~[spring-context-5.0.0.RC3.jar:5.0.0.RC3]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:122) ~[spring-boot-2.0.0.M3.jar:2.0.0.M3]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:750) ~[spring-boot-2.0.0.M3.jar:2.0.0.M3]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:386) ~[spring-boot-2.0.0.M3.jar:2.0.0.M3]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:327) ~[spring-boot-2.0.0.M3.jar:2.0.0.M3]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1245) ~[spring-boot-2.0.0.M3.jar:2.0.0.M3]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1233) ~[spring-boot-2.0.0.M3.jar:2.0.0.M3]
    at ca.naijaconnects.naijaconnectsproject.NaijaconnectsProjectApplication.main(NaijaconnectsProjectApplication.java:15) ~[classes/:na]
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'varchar2(40) not null, user_password varchar2(40) not null, primary key (user_na' at line 1
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:425) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.43.jar:5.1.43]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:408) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.43.jar:5.1.43]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:943) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.43.jar:5.1.43]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3973) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.43.jar:5.1.43]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3909) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.43.jar:5.1.43]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2527) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.43.jar:5.1.43]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2680) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.43.jar:5.1.43]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2490) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.43.jar:5.1.43]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2448) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.43.jar:5.1.43]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl.executeInternal(StatementImpl.java:845) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.43.jar:5.1.43]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl.execute(StatementImpl.java:745) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.43.jar:5.1.43]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyStatement.execute(ProxyStatement.java:92) ~[HikariCP-2.6.3.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyStatement.execute(HikariProxyStatement.java) ~[HikariCP-2.6.3.jar:na]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.GenerationTargetToDatabase.accept(GenerationTargetToDatabase.java:54) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.10.Final.jar:5.2.10.Final]
    ... 33 common frames omitted

[2m2017-09-10 02:50:18.820[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m16904[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[           main][0;39m [36mj.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean[0;39m [2m:[0;39m Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
[2m2017-09-10 02:50:18.920[0;39m [33m WARN[0;39m [35m16904[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[           main][0;39m [36mConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext[0;39m [2m:[0;39m Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'naijaConnectsController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'userLoginRepo'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'ca.naijaconnects.naijaconnectsproject.repo.UserLoginRepo' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
[2m2017-09-10 02:50:18.920[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m16904[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[           main][0;39m [36mj.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean[0;39m [2m:[0;39m Closing JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
[2m2017-09-10 02:50:18.920[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m16904[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[           main][0;39m [36mcom.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource      [0;39m [2m:[0;39m testdb - Shutdown initiated...
[2m2017-09-10 02:50:18.982[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m16904[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[           main][0;39m [36mcom.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource      [0;39m [2m:[0;39m testdb - Shutdown completed.
[2m2017-09-10 02:50:19.001[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m16904[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[           main][0;39m [36mo.apache.catalina.core.StandardService  [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Stopping service [Tomcat]
[2m2017-09-10 02:50:19.044[0;39m [33m WARN[0;39m [35m16904[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[           main][0;39m [36mo.s.b.c.e.EventPublishingRunListener    [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Error calling ApplicationEventListener

java.lang.ClassCastException: org.springframework.boot.context.event.ApplicationFailedEvent cannot be cast to org.springframework.boot.web.context.WebServerInitializedEvent
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.invokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:159) [spring-context-5.0.0.RC3.jar:5.0.0.RC3]
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:139) [spring-context-5.0.0.RC3.jar:5.0.0.RC3]
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:127) [spring-context-5.0.0.RC3.jar:5.0.0.RC3]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.event.EventPublishingRunListener.finished(EventPublishingRunListener.java:114) [spring-boot-2.0.0.M3.jar:2.0.0.M3]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.callFinishedListener(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:79) [spring-boot-2.0.0.M3.jar:2.0.0.M3]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.finished(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:72) [spring-boot-2.0.0.M3.jar:2.0.0.M3]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.handleRunFailure(SpringApplication.java:803) [spring-boot-2.0.0.M3.jar:2.0.0.M3]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:338) [spring-boot-2.0.0.M3.jar:2.0.0.M3]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1245) [spring-boot-2.0.0.M3.jar:2.0.0.M3]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1233) [spring-boot-2.0.0.M3.jar:2.0.0.M3]
    at ca.naijaconnects.naijaconnectsproject.NaijaconnectsProjectApplication.main(NaijaconnectsProjectApplication.java:15) [classes/:na]

[2m2017-09-10 02:50:19.065[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m16904[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[           main][0;39m [36mutoConfigurationReportLoggingInitializer[0;39m [2m:[0;39m 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the auto-configuration report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
[2m2017-09-10 02:50:19.840[0;39m [31mERROR[0;39m [35m16904[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[           main][0;39m [36mo.s.b.d.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter  [0;39m [2m:[0;39m 

***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Field userLoginRepo in ca.naijaconnects.naijaconnectsproject.controller.NaijaConnectsController required a bean of type 'ca.naijaconnects.naijaconnectsproject.repo.UserLoginRepo' that could not be found.


Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'ca.naijaconnects.naijaconnectsproject.repo.UserLoginRepo' in your configuration.
```

This is my pom.xml

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>ca.naijaconnects</groupId>
    <artifactId>naijaconnectsProject</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>naijaconnectsProject</name>
    <description>none</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.0.M3</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>

        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>

        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>8.0.15</version>
        </dependency>


        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.persistence/persistence-api -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-rest-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>

        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-data-jpa -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>

        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.javassist</groupId>
            <artifactId>javassist</artifactId>

        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-validation -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>

        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-libs-release</id>
            <name>Spring Releases</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/libs-release</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>

        <repository>
            <id>spring-snapshots</id>
            <name>Spring Snapshots</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/snapshot</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-milestones</id>
            <name>Spring Milestones</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>spring-snapshots</id>
            <name>Spring Snapshots</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/snapshot</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </pluginRepository>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>spring-milestones</id>
            <name>Spring Milestones</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>
</project>
```

This is my run application:-

```
package ca.naijaconnects.naijaconnectsproject;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.EnableJpaRepositories;

@SpringBootApplication
public class NaijaconnectsProjectApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        ApplicationContext factory = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext();
        SpringApplication.run(NaijaconnectsProjectApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

This is my configuration file:-

```
package ca.naijaconnects.naijaconnectsproject.config;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.EnableJpaRepositories;

import ca.naijaconnects.naijaconnectsproject.entity.UserLoginDetails;

@Configuration
@EnableJpaRepositories
public class ApplicationConfig 
{
    @Bean
    public UserLoginDetails userLoginDetails()
    {
        return new UserLoginDetails();
    }

}
```

This is my controller:-

```
package ca.naijaconnects.naijaconnectsproject.controller;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import ca.naijaconnects.naijaconnectsproject.entity.UserLoginDetails;
import ca.naijaconnects.naijaconnectsproject.repo.UserLoginRepo;

@Controller
@RequestMapping(value="/testing")
public class NaijaConnectsController 
{
    @Autowired
    UserLoginRepo userLoginRepo;



    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @RequestMapping(value = "/insertLogins", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public @ResponseBody List<UserLoginDetails> PostFormDataJSONArray() {   
        UserLoginDetails userLoginDetail = new UserLoginDetails();
        userLoginDetail.setUserName("timisenco");
        userLoginDetail.setUserPassword("Test@2017");
        return (List<UserLoginDetails>) userLoginRepo.save(userLoginDetail);
    }

}
```

This is my entity:-

```
package ca.naijaconnects.naijaconnectsproject.entity;
import java.io.Serializable;

import javax.persistence.*;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;

@Entity
//@Table(name = "userlogindetails")
public class UserLoginDetails 
{
    @Id
    @Column(name = "USER_NAME", nullable = false,columnDefinition="varchar2(40)")
    private String userName;

    @Column(name = "USER_Pawword", nullable = false,columnDefinition="varchar2(40)")
    private String userPassword;


    public UserLoginDetails()
    {

    }
    @Bean
    public String getUserName()
    {
        return userName;
    }
    @Bean
    public void setUserName(String userName)
    {
        this.userName = userName;
    }
    @Bean
    public String getUserPassword()
    {
        return userPassword;
    }
    @Bean
    public void setUserPassword(String userPasword)
    {
        this.userPassword = userPassword;
    }
}
```

This is the repo:-

```
package ca.naijaconnects.naijaconnectsproject.repo;

import java.util.List;

import javax.sql.DataSource;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.*;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import ca.naijaconnects.naijaconnectsproject.entity.UserLoginDetails;

@org.springframework.data.rest.core.annotation.RepositoryRestResource(exported=false)
public interface UserLoginRepo extends JpaRepository<UserLoginDetails, String>
{

    //UserLoginDetails findOne(String);
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    UserLoginDetails save(UserLoginDetails account);
    //UserLoginDetails findByEmailAddress(EmailAddress emailAddress);
}
```

My Application Properties:-

```
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost/naijaconnectsdb
spring.datasource.username=naijaConnects
spring.datasource.password=Connects@2017
spring.datasource.name=naijaconnectsdb
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update //fixed it after comments
spring.jpa.generate-ddl=true
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.data.jpa.repositories.enabled=true
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
```

Comment: it should be update. spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update

Comment: still having the same issue

Comment: update the logs

Comment: done that. thank you

Comment: just edit the question you will be able too.

Comment: issue in 2.0.0.M3? how about 1.5.6.RELEASE. is this project in github.

Answer (score 0):

I can see lots of errors. As you requested suggested ways of debugging, here it goes.

1. Clean up your pom.xml. It's very dirty and hard to understand. As you are using spring-boot and spring boot jpa remove following dependencies for now.

   ```
   <dependency>
       <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
       <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
   </dependency>
   <dependency>
       <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
       <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
   </dependency>
   <dependency>
       <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
       <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
   </dependency>
   <dependency>
       <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
       <artifactId>spring-data-rest-core</artifactId>
   </dependency>
   ```

Also a dependency is added twice:-

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

Remove it.

You could later once applications runs could use these dependencies as per your need.

2. I would recommend using release version of springboot for now. Hence change 2.0.0.M3 to 2.0.0.M3 in parent spring boot dependency.
3. Fix your `application.properties` file as it has lots of problems. Below is a updated one:-

   ```
   spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
   spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/naijaconnectsdb
   spring.datasource.username=naijaConnects
   spring.datasource.password=Connects@2017
   spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update //fixed it after comments
   spring.jpa.generate-ddl=true
   spring.jpa.show-sql=true
   spring.data.jpa.repositories.enabled=true
   spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
   ```

Please try following and then see what exception you get and try to troubleshoot from there.

Comment: Thank you, that one works. I have updated the logs to show the new errors

Comment: @timisenco you should observe the logs carefully. It says syntax error in mysql. Please fix that.

Comment: @timisenco seems a mysql version issue.